# follow up on hash table c++ , this->next = NULL pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this, hashtable

this is a follow up to another question I had and it's in regards to the 
**this->next = NULL** pointer inside the HashNode constructor below . 
My question is , I can't see why **htable[hash_val]->next** does not equal NULL and instead actually has a memory address , even if **this->next = NULL** , as written in the constructor .

Can anybody tell me why **htable[hash_val]->next** doesn't equal NULL and has an address associated with it . Can't seem to find it after looking for a while . I can see that **htable[hash_val]** will have a value but I would think **htable[hash_val]->next** would be NULL .  Thanks .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int TABLE_SIZE = 128;

class HashNode
{
    public:
    int key;
    int value;
    HashNode* next;
    HashNode(int key, int value)
    {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
        this->next = NULL; // shouldn't htable[hash_val]->next = NULL 
    }
};


class HashMap
{
    private:
    HashNode** htable;

    public:
    HashMap()
    {
        htable = new HashNode*[TABLE_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
            htable[i] = NULL;
    }


    int HashFunc(int key)
    {
        return key % TABLE_SIZE;
    }

    /*
     * Insert Element at a key
     */
    void Insert(int key, int value)
    {
        int hash_val = HashFunc(key);
        HashNode* prev = NULL;
        HashNode* entry = htable[hash_val];

        while (entry != NULL)
        {
            prev = entry;
            entry = entry->next;
         }
        if (entry == NULL)
        {
            entry = new HashNode(key, value);

            if (prev == NULL)
        {
                htable[hash_val] = entry;
            }
        else
        {
                prev->next = entry;

            }
        }

    }
    void testnull(int key){
        int hash_val = HashFunc(key);
        cout<<htable[hash_val]->next;  // outputs an address , not NULL
    }
   int Search(int key)
       {
        bool flag = false;
        int hash_val = HashFunc(key);
        HashNode* entry = htable[hash_val];
        while (entry != NULL)
        {
            if (entry->key == key)
        {
                cout<<entry->value<<" ";
                flag = true;
            }
            entry = entry->next;
        }
        if (!flag)
            return -1;
        }
  };


int main() {

HashMap hash; 

hash.Insert(3,7);
hash.Insert(3,8);
hash.testnull(3);


// your code goes here
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inserted two elements with same key.
Your class doesn't have 'equals' comparison so every time you add new element it is being put into same pocket (same hash code) but as next record (considering keys are not equal). That's why you have two records. and next record for first one is not null. I most reak Hash map implementations if you add new record with same key it should replace previous one.

i'd change code like this:

```
        while (entry != NULL)
        {
            if(entry->key == key)
            {
                entry->value = value;
                return; 
            }
            prev = entry;
            entry = entry->next;
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses ,  @Anthony D , it's not homework , didn't know leaving comments makes it homework :) , but anyways , back to understanding this .  I see you're saying that adding 7 and 8 for the **value** parameters , it's inserting those values as you've shown , and the **next**  " quite normally" gets the value 8 after 7 .

Comment: In other words ,  **this->value** gets the first value and **this->next** gets the second value , is that you are saying ? What about a 3rd value being input , which pointer would be it's lvalue ?

Comment: "and the next " quite normally" gets the value 8 after 7". It's not really correct. in case your hash table size is 4 ant your keys are 3 and 7 hash for both of them is 3 (3%4 == 7%4). So they'll go into same pocket but into different places in list. eg 3 is in entry and 7 is in entry-> next. Next unique key with same has goes into entry->next->next etc. Once you get record by hash you should search for exact key in containing list.  If you put two values with not only same hash but same key it should replace previous one. In your code this comparison is missing.

Comment: Thanks Vadim , I was looking at the code again , and I think I know what I was missing . In the **Insert** function with the **prev = entry** , the **prev** pointer is (sharing) the address of **entry** and later in the **Insert** function , **prev->next=entry** is the same as **entry->next=entry**  since both **prev** and **entry** share the same address .

Comment: Thx Vadim , your added code helps a lot with two of the same keys

Comment: @ldc57   prev = entry;
              entry = entry->next; don't think they are the same...

Comment: In the Insert function ,
    while(entry != NULL){
        prev=entry;   

and , 
     else
          {
             prev->next = entry;
      }

Comment: The code and my comments said prev->next = entry  and entry->next = entry being the same , entry=entry->next wasn't brought up , not sure what you mean currently

Comment: Sorry , I meant **entry=entry->next**    not **entry->next = entry**    and 

since **prev = entry , prev->next = entry->next**  , both of those having the same address and their respective int values at that address , I need to include the Search function which has the same **entry=entry->next** in it's while loop

Comment: Probably I've misunderstood you. prev and entry are just local variables. Maybe you added additional meaning to entry. But in this code prev and entry share the same value only in this line prev = entry . in next line value of entry is being changed. in else clause  prev has old entry value but entry variable contains newly created object. also this comparison  "if (entry == NULL)" in existing code is useless

Comment: Yes in the Insert function , the entry = entry->next;   becomes NULL  .   Which is what confused me when I came to the Search function . I couldn't see how entry = entry->next  in the Search function wasn't also NULL and was actually outputting memory address values . When you mention the locality of the variables , I will look at that more . And when I say **prev->next = entry>next**  it looks like I should say **entry->next = prev->next**  instead , but the comparison is not local so it might not matter. Basically I am not seeing where **entry->next** in Search function gets its values from

Comment: Lets say before first insert your htable[hash_val] is null. after insert htable[hash_val]  has an object. htable[hash_val] ->next is null. after second insert htable[hash_val] ->next has an object. htable[hash_val] ->next->next is null etc....

Comment: your entity and prev are just local variables to iterate trough this chain.if you add more keys you'll have htable[hash_val] ->next-next->next->...->next->(next = null). But this is still oncorrect because you sould have list of values with same key hash, but with only one occurrence for each key.

Comment: Thanks Vadim , I understand the result that is happening , that the new values are being stored on ->next but I am trying to see exactly how its done in the code . Exactly where in the code does it make it store those values there. Or does the allocation of new  (new HashNode(key,value) automatically store that new address at ->next

Comment: No. It just assigns it to local variable.it stores this value in if else clause right after allocation. If - if first record , else - otherwise

Comment: Ok . At htable[hash_val] = entry. Where entry is the new allocation right above it . htable[hash_val] is getting the value from entry . The same value . So it looks like the new entry gets the ->next allocated at that point and then htable[hash_val] from there. Sorry to ask , you have been a real help Vadim . Much appreciated

Comment: The new entry has next fiels. And it is null.  after next insert after  while (entry != NULL)
        {
            prev = entry;
            entry = entry->next;
         } the entry variable  is null and prev has pointer to the latest added HashNode object.  [prev->next = entry] initializes  next field of last added entry with new HashNode  object. so you have htable[hash_val](HashNode obj1)->next(HashNode obj2)->next(NULL)

Comment: Yes thank you Vadim . I pretty much have my head wrapped around this now , thanks a lot to you . The local variables are sharing addresses . Prev will have the same address as entry , then later prev->next will point to the new entry ( Yes , entry goes to NULL shortly after but the addresses are being reserved at certain points in the function ). SO is helping a lot , otherwise would be taking twice as long or longer to figure out , just wish I would stop sending the comments by pressing Enter before I am ready to write , lol

Comment: It looks like in **Search** ,  entry->next isn't sharing any address with any  memory address from **Insert** , so it's actually exclusive to **Search**

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment . Yes , it does share the same address at prev->next in **Insert** and entry->next in **Search** . Finally , thx .

Answer (score 0):

Of course `htable[hash_val]->next` isn't NULL. You are using a linked list collision solving.

1) Initially:

```
[0] -> NULL
 |
...
 |
[3] -> NULL
 |
...
```

2) You insert 7 at key 3.

```
[0] -> NULL
 |
...
 |
[3] -> 7 -> NULL
 |
...
```

3) You insert 8 at key 3 (the *same* key as 7).

```
[0] -> NULL
 |
...
 |
[3] -> 7 -> 8 -> NULL
 |
...
```

It is quite normal that `7`'s next is `8`, because the key of both of them is 3. Thus, your code is doing exactly what it should.

**P.S.** : It would save you (and us) time if you understood, or at least *had* your class lesson next to you before starting to do that homework (`// your code goes here` gives you away). On Stack Overflow, you should ask a question only once you've shown you've really tried to find the answer to your problem. After all SO is made to help professionals, students and others with their daily-life programming concerns, NOT to have someone look at your homework for you! :)